# How do I add \textbf to a description in my class file?

Tags: lists, description

I am not a tex guru, but I need to modify my existing command `\description` to include boldtext.

Here is the command snippet:

```
    \def\description{\@ifnextchar[{\@describe}{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@
\labelsep=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\leftmargini=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\leftmargin=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\itemindent-\leftmargin \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}}
```

Where and how and why do I insert `\bfseries` or `\textbf` to change the label to a bold version?

---

Additional information

```
% adjusted environment "description"
% if an optional parameter (at the first two levels of lists)
% is present, its width is considered to be the widest mark
% throughout the current list.
\def\description{\@ifnextchar[{\@describe}{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@
\labelsep=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\leftmargini=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\leftmargin=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
\itemindent-\leftmargin \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}}
%
\def\describelabel#1{#1\hfil}
\def\@describe[#1]{\labelsep=12pt\relax
\relax\ifnum\@listdepth=0
\setitemindent{#1}\else\ifnum\@listdepth=1
\setitemitemindent{#1}\fi\fi
\list{--}{\let\makelabel\describelabel}}
%
```

Comment: This isn't the full definition. You need to also copy the definitions of `\@describe` and `\descriptionlabel`.

Comment: Why use this instead of the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to create a new environment modeled on `description` that has boldface labels, the best way is to use `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{bolddesc}{description}{4}
\setlist[bolddesc]{font=\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{bolddesc}
\item[Gnu] is a large animal

\item[Gnat] is a small animal
\end{bolddesc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This actually doesn't give anything different from the standard environment, but `enumitem` has lots of bells and whistles to modify the appearance of a list environment.

Comment: This can be achieved by using the default `description` environment of latex itself (by just `\begin{description}` and `\end{description`}). No need of using an extra package (`enumitem`)

Comment: @HarishKumar Of course; it was just by way of example. It's hard to understand what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree. That was just for information to the OP. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the snippet plus describe and so on: